# Django - CreateView with DetailView

Tags: python, django, calendar, django-views

I'm trying to make a web page with calendars. Every calendar have events.

I'm trying to make a form to add an event to a calendar. We can make this if we click on "Add new event" on a certain calendar.

So, as I understand I would need two views combined -  DetailView (to know on which calendar we should put our event) and CreateView.

This is how I'm making this:

```
class EventCreate(CreateView):
model = Event
form_class = EventForm
success_url = '/prijavljen/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.calendar = self.request.calendar
    return super(EventCreate, self).form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(EventCreate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['calendar'] = self.model
    return context
```

But it's not working, I don't event get calendar when I click on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it doesn't work because `self.model` is a class, not an instance. As far as I understand you have two models: Event and Calendar. Event has a foreign key to Calendar. To make it work you should create a calendar instance and pass it into `form.instance.calendar`. Perhaps, you should do something like this in `get_context_data`:

```
context['calendar'] = Calendar.objects.get(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view you posted, `self.model` refers to the line `model = Event`, so you're trying to set `context['calendar']` to an event, not a calendar. You would need to check whether `self.request.calendar` is actually a calendar model instance, and if so, try `context['calendar'] = self.request.calendar`.

However, how are you setting `self.request.calendar`? I suspect that might be the source of a bug unless you're using Middleware to solve that. (`request.user` as you probably saw in the docs is added by [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user).

You should be adding the calendar as a default value, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277444/set-initial-value-in-createview-from-foreignkey-non-self-request-user) for how to do that.