# How to set up initial value in Django form for ForeignKey field?

Tags: python, django

I have problem with setting up initial value for ForeignKey field. I have a `CreateView` form and I am accessing it from book detail view which has url : `path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),` I want to have initial value of this book for example `/book/4` in my form already when i enter `CreateView`

views.py

```
class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
    initial = {'book': BookInstance.book.id}
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.book.pk})
```

I was trying to access a book with : `initial = {'book': BookInstance.book.id}` but i got error: initial = {'book': BookInstance.book.id}
AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'id'

Here are my models.py:

```
    class Book(models.Model):
        """Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book)."""
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

        # Foreign Key used because book can only have one author, but authors can have multiple books
        # Author as a string rather than object because it hasn't been declared yet in the file.
        summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the book')
        isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13, help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>')

        # ManyToManyField used because genre can contain many books. Books can cover many genres.
        # Genre class has already been defined so we can specify the object above.
        genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')
        language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            """String for representing the Model object."""
            return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            """Returns the url to access a detail record for this book."""
            return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

        def display_genre(self):
            """Create a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin."""
            return ', '.join(genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3])

        display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'

class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library)."""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular book across whole library')
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('m', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LOAN_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='m',
        help_text='Book availability',
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets have a closer look at `BookInstance.book.id`.

`BookInstance` -> A model class

`book` -> An unpopulated field in that model (`ForwardManyToOneDescriptor`, with emphasis on `Descriptor`)

`id` -> A field that django internally populates from the database when we use something like `Book.objects.first().id`

Therefore, you're trying to get a book foreign key from a model `class` **not** a model `instance`.

You'll probably want to use something similar to [set initial value in CreateView from ForeignKey (non-self.request.user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277444/set-initial-value-in-createview-from-foreignkey-non-self-request-user) here. You can access the request object from within the `get_initial` method.

So here's what it might look like:

```
class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'

    def get_initial(self):
        # You could even get the Book model using Book.objects.get here!
        return {
            'book': self.kwargs["pk"]
        }

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.book.pk})
```

Comment: `def get_initial(self):
        # You could even get the Book model using Book.objects.get here!
        getid = Book.objects.get(Book.id)
        return {
            'book': getid
        }`

It raises error : TypeError at /catalog/book/create/instance

cannot unpack non-iterable DeferredAttribute object

Comment: Not sure where you're getting `Book.objects.get(Book.id)` from. Try just using `Book.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])` there instead.

Comment: I am getting KeyError: 'pk' then

Comment: Whoops. I'm sorry - I presumed that you had a "pk" url parameter in your urlpattern for that BookInstanceCreate View. Where do you want to get the pk/id from then? If you just want to set it to a static value, you can just use `Book.objects.get(id=<id for book you want to default to>)`.

Comment: I want to get a pk parameter from `path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),` It is a previous page and it has to recognise which book it is and initially set in a form, I have already managed to redirect properly for detail page but i don't know how to get initial id from Book objects

Comment: Okay i just edited urlpath to `path('book/<int:pk>/create/instance', views.BookInstanceCreate.as_view(), name='book_create_instance')` It was easier to do than i was trying, i tried to do it by round. Problem solved thanks for help

Comment: Great! In case you've figured it out, it would be great if you could mark the answer as correct in case others come across the same requirement in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     model = BookInstance
     fields = '__all__'
     ermission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
     def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.book.pk})
```

You can't access the value from the class name

```
initial = {'book': BookInstance.book.id}
```

It should be the object of that class.

Comment: I am confused how to get it working, I need to access `id` exactly how i got `pk` to redirect back to proper book detail page. Shouldn't it be something like this:
`def get_initial(self):
        initial = {'book': self.object.book.id}
        return initial`