# How to set initial value of ForeignKey dynamically in CreateView?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I want to set dynamically initial value of ForeignKey in CreateView. But is there any simple way to do this ?
And I tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277444/set-initial-value-in-createview-from-foreignkey-non-self-request-user) (as answer of this link). But it is not working.
How can I pass the album(ForeignKey) to the field in CreateView?

## models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    credit = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('picture:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.credit


class Item(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('upload_date', 'caption')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('picture:item-detail', kwargs={ 'id': self.album_id , 'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

## views.py

```
class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Item
    fields = ['album', 'file_type', 'caption']

    def get_initial(self):
        album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=self.kwargs.get('album.pk'))
        return {
            'album': album,
            'file_type': 't',
        }
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# /picture/<album_id>/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
# /picture/<album_id>/<pic_id>
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item-detail'),
# /picture/<album_id>/pic/add
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/pic/add/$', views.ItemCreate.as_view(), name='item-add'),
]
```

Comment: What happens when you replace this `get_object_or_404(Album, pk=self.kwargs.get('album.pk'))` with `get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs.get('album'))`?

Comment: It's 404 No Album matches the given query. at both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the object(`album`) where album.pk == `id` ( `id` an URL parameter of `'item-add'` ) then try this,

```
class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Item
    fields = ['album', 'file_type', 'caption']

    def get_initial(self):
        album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=self.kwargs['id'])
        return {
            'album': album,
            'file_type': 't',
        }
```